# Modifications in a graphic with matplotlib

Tags: python, scheduling

I am currently working on automating the creation of a shift schedule for a project. I want to hand over my code a list of 0 or 1, and whenever the list contains a 1 at a specific point a squres (indicator for shift) appears. So far so good. It already works like a charm but one thing doesnt work as i want it to work. Whenever i have two doctors working the same shift, i.e. both or all three have a 1 at the same place in the list, only one square is displayed (always the latter one). How do i need the code in order to do this:
Whenever there is more than one shift, i.e. two or three, i want the code to display the additional square on top of each other.
Lets say, the lists look like this:

```
doctor1 = [0,1,0,...]
doctor2 = [0,1,1,...]
doctor2 = [1,1,0,...]
```

This implies that all three work shift two on day 1. Now i want that the first squares has the coordinates (see code below) (1.4, 0), the one for doctor 2 (1.4, 1) and for doctor three (1.4, 3).

Another example:

```
doctor1 = [0,0,0,...]
doctor2 = [0,1,1,...]
doctor2 = [1,1,0,...]
```

Now doctor 2 should have the coordinates (1.4, 0) and doctor 3 (1.4, 1).

For the last example:

```
doctor1 = [0,1,0,...]
doctor2 = [0,1,1,...]
doctor2 = [1,0,0,...]
```

Doctor 1 should have the coordinates (1.4, 0) and doctor 3 (1.4, 1).

How would i achieve that?

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Patch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

# Plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis("off")

# Lists
changes = [4, 2, 3]
doctor_1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
doctor_2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
doctor_3 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

# Coordinats
positions = [(0.3, 0), (1.4, 0), (2.5, 0),
             (3.7, 0), (4.8, 0), (5.9, 0),
             (7.1, 0), (8.2, 0), (9.3, 0),
             (10.5, 0), (11.6, 0), (12.7, 0),
             (13.9, 0), (15, 0), (16.1, 0),
             (17.3, 0), (18.4, 0), (19.5, 0),
             (20.7, 0), (21.8, 0), (22.9, 0),
             (24.1, 0), (25.2, 0), (26.3, 0),
             (0.3, -3.5), (1.4, -3.5),(2.5, -3.5),
             (3.7, -3.5), (4.8, -3.5), (5.9, -3.5),
             (7.1, -3.5), (8.2, -3.5), (9.3, -3.5),
             (10.5, -3.5), (11.6, -3.5), (12.7, -3.5),
             (13.9, -3.5), (15, -3.5), (16.1, -3.5),
             (17.4, -3.5), (18.4, -3.5), (19.5, -3.5)]

# Colors
colors = ['teal', 'orange', 'violet']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis("off")

# Plot
for day in range(14):
    for shift in range(3):
        index = day * 3 + shift
        if doctor_1[index] == 1:
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle(positions[index], 1, 1, facecolor=colors[0], edgecolor="black"))
        if doctor_2[index] == 1:
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle(positions[index], 1, 1, facecolor=colors[1], edgecolor="black"))
        if doctor_3[index] == 1:
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle(positions[index], 1, 1, facecolor=colors[2], edgecolor="black"))

# Legend
ax.arrow(0, 0, 28.5, 0, length_includes_head=False)
ax.plot([0, 28.5], [0, 0], 'k-', linewidth=1)  # X-Achse
ax.arrow(0, -3.5, 21.7, 0, length_includes_head=True, head_width=0.5, head_length=0.5)
ax.plot([0, 21.7], [-3.5, -3.5], 'k-', linewidth=1)  # X-Achse

# Plot 1
# Day 1
ax.plot([0.2, 0.2], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.plot([3.6, 3.6], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.text(1.9, -0.8, "Day 1", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 2
ax.plot([7, 7], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.text(5.3, -0.8, "Day 2", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 3
ax.plot([10.4, 10.4], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.text(8.7, -0.8, "Day 3", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 4
ax.plot([13.8, 13.8], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.text(12.1, -0.8, "Day 4", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 5
ax.plot([17.2, 17.2], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.text(15.5, -0.8, "Day 5", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 6
ax.plot([20.6, 20.6], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.text(18.9, -0.8, "Day 6", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 7
ax.plot([24, 24], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.text(22.3, -0.8, "Day 7", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 8
ax.plot([27.4, 27.4], [-0.5, 1.5], 'k-')
ax.text(25.7, -0.8, "Day 8", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 9
ax.plot([0.2, 0.2], [-4, -2], 'k-')
ax.plot([3.6, 3.6], [-4, -2], 'k-')
ax.text(1.9, -4.3, "Day 9", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 10
ax.plot([7, 7], [-4, -2], 'k-')
ax.text(5.3, -4.3, "Day 10", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 11
ax.plot([10.4, 10.4], [-4, -2], 'k-')
ax.text(8.7, -4.3, "Day 11", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 12
ax.plot([13.8, 13.8], [-4, -2], 'k-')
ax.text(12.1, -4.3, "Day 12", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 13
ax.plot([17.2, 17.2], [-4, -2], 'k-')
ax.text(15.5, -4.3, "Day 13", weight="bold", ha="center")

# Day 14
ax.plot([20.6, 20.6], [-4, -2], 'k-')
ax.text(18.9, -4.3, "Day 14", weight="bold", ha="center")


ax.arrow(0, 0, 28.5, 0, length_includes_head=False)
ax.plot([0, 28.5], [0, 0], 'k-', linewidth=1) # X-axis line
ax.arrow(0, -3.5, 21.7, 0, length_includes_head=True, head_width=0.5, head_length=0.5)
ax.plot([0, 21.7], [-3.5, -3.5], 'k-', linewidth=1) # X-axis line

# Legende
legend_elements = [
    Patch(facecolor="teal", edgecolor="black", hatch="//", label="Worker 1"),
    Patch(facecolor="orange", edgecolor="black", hatch="|", label="Worker 2"),
    Patch(facecolor="violet", edgecolor="black", hatch="...", label="Worker 3"),
    Patch(facecolor="grey", edgecolor="black", hatch="\\\\", label="Overstaffing"),
    Patch(facecolor="red", edgecolor="black", hatch="///", label="Understaffing"),
    Patch(facecolor="black", edgecolor="black", hatch="+++", label="Performance decrease"),
]


# Text "Shift Changes"
ax.text(25, -2.2, "Shift Changes", weight="bold", ha="center", va="center", fontsize=12)
ax.text(24, -3.3, "3", color="teal", weight="bold", ha="center", va="center", fontsize=12)
ax.text(25, -3.3, "2", color="orange", weight="bold", ha="center", va="center", fontsize=12)
ax.text(26, -3.3, "2", color="violet", weight="bold", ha="center", va="center", fontsize=12)
box_positions = [(24, -3.2), (25, -3.2), (26, -3.2)]
colors = ['teal', 'orange', 'violet']

for i, change in enumerate(changes):
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((box_positions[i][0] - 0.5, box_positions[i][1] - 0.5), 1, 1, facecolor=colors[i]))

    ax.text(box_positions[i][0], box_positions[i][1], str(change), color="black", weight="bold", ha="center",
            va="center", fontsize=12)
rect = Rectangle((25.5, -8.5), 3, 3, fill=False, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5)
ax.add_patch(rect)

line_coords = [(25.5, -8.5), (28.5, -8.5), (28.5, -5.5), (25.5, -5.5), (25.5, -8.5)]
line = mlines.Line2D(*zip(*line_coords), color='black', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5)
ax.add_line(line)

ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc="upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.4), ncol=3, fancybox=True)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.ylim(-5, 2)
plt.show()
```

Updated code:

```
for day in range(num_days):
    for shift in range(3):
        index = day * 3 + shift
        doctors = [doctor_1, doctor_2, doctor_3, overstaffing_list, understaffing_list]
        offset = np.array((0,0))
        for doctor, color in zip(doctors, colors):
            if doctor[index] == 1:
                position = np.array(positions[index]) + offset
                hatch_pattern = ''
                if color == 'teal':
                    hatch_pattern = '//'
                elif color == 'orange':
                    hatch_pattern = '|'
                elif color == 'violet':
                    hatch_pattern = '...'
                ax.add_patch(Rectangle(position, 1, 1, facecolor=color, edgecolor="black", hatch=hatch_pattern))
                offset[-1] += 1
```

I searched the net and other forums.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is you use the same `positions[index]` for all three doctors. How about you define some offset per doctor and apply it for each doctor respectively? For example:

```
for day in range(14):
    for shift in range(3):
        index = day * 3 + shift
        doctors = [doctor_1, doctor_2, doctor_3]
        offset = np.array((0,0))
        for doctor, color in zip(doctor, colors):
            if doctor[index] == 1:
                position = np.array(positions[index]) + offset
                ax.add_patch(Rectangle(position, 1, 1, facecolor=color, edgecolor="black"))
                offset[-1] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Nevertheless, do you also have an idea how I can implement my idea?

Comment: Which idea exactly?

Comment: That not every doctor has his own series per-se, but that the whole thing adapts dynamically, so to speak. So that the y-position of an artzes 2 or 3 depends on whether there is already a doctor who has the same shift, as described above.

Comment: Yeah, I see, I've changed the code in the answer, now offset is generated for each day separately

Comment: You are a legend, thank you. I still have one small additional question. I also have a list of shift with overstaffing and one with understaffing. This should be included in the plot mutein. Also here boxes should appear if there is a 1 in the list, with a difference. All shifts with undercoverage should be on top, as the code already does, but with overcoverage it looks different. If for example on day 2 and shift 2 only one worker is used, but the model comes to two, then logically two squares are added.

Comment: But since overstaffing is present here, the upper one should have the colors of the overstaffing block and no additional square on top. With overstaffing, the upper square is replaced, so to speak. I have adapted the code above a bit.

Comment: Would be really helpful!